# Send .ovpn profile from iOS app to official openVPN client with url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, openvpn

in my app I have ovpn profile (for example, in Document directory). I'd like to send (share) this file to official client openVPN.

I've implemented this:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
var installed: Bool? = nil
if let url = URL(string: "openvpn://") {
    installed = app.canOpenURL(url)
}

guard installed ?? false, let url = URL(string: "openvpn://") else {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id590379981?mt=8") {
        app.open(url)
    }
    return
}
app.open(url)
```

And this works great, but I don't know how to improve url scheme and, accordingly, I don't know how to send my file to "Import Profile" screen. Could you share your experience?

Yes, I know about `UIActivityViewController`

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ovpnUrlPath], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but there are additional user's actions, but it's again works great: profile file is opened on "Import Profile" screen as expected:

[image]

Question is: how to share my ovpn with url scheme for openVPN?

Answer (score 0):

I've received comment from official openVPN account:

```
unfortunately, OpenVPN Connect client application doesn't have functionality for sharing connection profiles.
```

so, right now it's impossible.